# How to subset multiple data frame efficiently in 'R'?

Tags: r, subset, lapply, netcdf

I have a large 'NetCDF' file of atmospheric PM10 data. You can download from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByY3OAw62EShbkF6VWNFUkRYMmM/view?usp=sharing).I am explaining details about my problem.

This ncdf file has 8 variables like this.

```
[1] "file ~/Downloads/2012_03_05_PM10_surface.nc has 8 dimensions:"
[1] "data_num   Size: 683016"
[1] "ncl1   Size: 683016"
[1] "obsnum_urban   Size: 250"
[1] "ID_LAT_LON   Size: 3"
[1] "obsnum_road   Size: 33"
[1] "obsnum_background   Size: 5"
[1] "obsnum_rural   Size: 16"
[1] "ncl7   Size: 683016"
[1] "------------------------"
[1] "file ~/Downloads/2012_03_05_PM10_surface.nc has 8 variables:"
[1] "int TMSID[data_num]  Longname:TMSID Missval:NA"
[1] "int TIME[ncl1]  Longname:TIME Missval:NA"
[1] "float PM10[data_num]  Longname:PM10 Missval:1e+30"
[1] "float urban[ID_LAT_LON,obsnum_urban]  Longname:urban Missval:1e+30"
[1] "float road[ID_LAT_LON,obsnum_road]  Longname:road Missval:1e+30"
[1] "float background[ID_LAT_LON,obsnum_background]  Longname:background Missval:1e+30"
[1] "float rural[ID_LAT_LON,obsnum_rural]  Longname:rural Missval:1e+30"
[1] "int TMS_JULIAN[ncl7]  Longname:TMS_JULIAN Missval:NA"
```

Here, My interest is only 4 variables. They are:

TIMSID is number of sites (its include urban site, rural site, road, background etc.)

urban :: number of urban sites [urban is 3 row 250 column matrix. row1 is number of urban sites , row2 is latidude, row 3 is longitude.]

TIME :: data was collected from 1 march 2012, 1.00 a.m. to may 2012 [encoding for 'time' is YYYYMMDDHH]

PM10 :: hourly particulate matter concentration measured at every station of every site

From this ncdf file I have already subset the PM10 values only for urban sites for 1 march 2012 1 a.m. (2012030101). Here, as you know, TMSID is id of all site but I wanted to subset only for urban sites (not for rural, road etc.) so I matched only the urban id from TMSID for march 1 2012, 1 a.m. That means I have subsetted only 1 hours PM10 data of 1 march for urban sites. I used following code:

```
library(ncdf)
nc<-open.ncdf("2012_03_05_PM10_surface.nc")
print(nc)

urban<-get.var.ncdf(nc,"urban")
time<-get.var.ncdf(nc,"TIME")
pm10<-get.var.ncdf(nc,"PM10")
tmsid<-get.var.ncdf(nc,"TMSID")
urban<-as.data.frame(t(urban))
colnames(urban)<-c("ID","LAT","LON")

urban311<-lapply(urban$ID,
                 function(x)data.frame(ID=x,time=2012030101,
                                       PM10=pm10[tmsid%in%x &
                                                   time%in%2012030101]))
urban311<-do.call(rbind,urban311)
urban311<-merge(urban311,urban,by="ID")
urban311
urban311<-subset(urban311,select=c("time","ID","LAT","LON","PM10"))

seoul311<-subset(urban311, LAT>=36.8 & LAT <=38 & LON>=126.4 & LON<= 127.3)
rownames(seoul311)<-NULL
```

In last 2 line of above code, I have subset PM10 values only for certain area from the urban sites according to latitude and longitude. and finally I got a dataframe like this.

```
              time     ID      LAT      LON PM10
    1   2012030101 111121 37.56464 126.9760   42
    2   2012030101 111123 37.57203 127.0050   37
    .
    .
    .
   106  2012030101 831153 37.49195 126.7533   68
   107  2012030101 831154 37.52662 126.8064   57
```

As you know, this is a data frame for only 1 march 1.00 a.m. Now I want to do the same work for every hour from 1 march to 7 march. That means I want to get (7*24) data frame. How can I do this efficiently?

Please, ask me if you have any further question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: so the only thing you need to do is from the `urban311` line on and just change `time%in%2012030101` to `time%in%2012030102`, `time%in%2012030103`, etc? wrap those lines in a function, have it return the data set, and use `lapply` to get a list of data frames for each hour. would that work?

Comment: @rawr, I am very beginner in R. so probably I cant understand your thought. But I can do this work by pasting the same code (7*24) times and just replace the time like 20120302,20120303 etc.. but this getting so lengthy and clumsy.

Comment: I strongly, *strongly* recommend to use the `raster` package. It's amazing. In this case it would make things so much simpler. Its documentation is excellent. Also, consider using `ncdf4` instead of `ncdf`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to use `lapply` here.
Also, rather than getting 7*24 dataframes, it would make more sense to have *one* dataframe with all the dates, and then you can subset it as necessary.

This all happens instead of your `urban311` stuff.
First make a list of all the `time`s we want to keep:

```
dts.to.get <- seq(as.POSIXct('2012-03-01 01:00'), as.POSIXct('2012-03-07 00:00'), by='1 hour')
# convert to the 2012030101 numeric format you have
dts.number <- as.numeric(format(dts.to.get, '%Y%m%d%H'))
```

Then work out which indices are urban IDs and have the right time:

```
i <- tmsid %in% urban$ID & time %in% dts.number
x <- data.frame(ID=as.vector(tmsid[i]), time=as.vector(time[i]), PM10=as.vector(pm10[i]))
```

Note that `subset(x, time==2012030101)` is your `urban311`. `x` has all the different date-times you were after in it.

Then if you want the `LAT` and `LON` added in, use `merge` like before. Note that since each ID appears 7*64 times this is replicated 168 times in your dataframe, so perhaps you are better off keeping them separate.

```
x <- merge(x, urban, by='ID')
```

There's no need to do the extra `subset(urban311, select=c("time", "ID", "LAT", "LON", "PM10"))` because they're the only columns `urban311` has anyway.

If you really *really* want to split up `x` into one dataframe per date-hour, then you could do

```
lapply(unique(x$time), function (tt) subset(df, time == tt))
```

to get a list of dataframes, but really, it isn't worth it. Takes ages and is quicker to just `subset` as needed.

Comment: what I understand that is If I want to make (7*24) different dataset/dataframe then I have to copy-paste `subset(x, time==2012030101)`  for (7*24) times for every hour by replacing time. am I right?  isn't it very lengthy? I don't know , is it possible to make (7*24) different dataset little bit shortly or not.

Comment: Another question is,
You write a code like `x <- data.frame(ID=as.vector(tmsid[i]), time=as.vector(time[i]), PM10=as.vector(pm10[i]))`

But even if I write in this way `x<-data.frame(ID=tmsid[i], Time=time[i], PM10=pm10[i])` then I got the out put same. why this is happening?

Comment: First question: my `lapply` line does that all for you, where every element of the list is one of your dataframes. You don't want to name them all individually or else you have to type out each line as you have mentioned; hence, I keep them in a list. Second question: there's no real difference between using `as.vector` or not, I just noticed that if you don't, `class(x$ID)` etc will be 'array' rather than a numeric vector like with most dataframes. I don't know why this is, and I don't think it will make a difference to be honest.

Comment: do you mean if I want (7*24) separate data frames object, I have to write `subset(x, time==2012030101)` this code (7*24) times? or there is any way of making loop by which I can make (7*24) data frame object by 1 or 2 line? sorry, I am beginner in r.

because I have to draw semi-variogram for each hour data. If I have a list of (7*24) data frames then how can I work with one dataframe from that list?

Comment: No, you don't have to write `subset` 168 times, I have already mentioned how you can use `lapply` to do it all at once. If you want to work with one dataframe from that list, use list subsetting to get that dataframe out, or a loop/lapply to operate on each of the data frames.

Comment: @mathematival.coffe , I found some problem in your answer. In the first line, you wrote `seq(as.POSIXct('2012-03-01 01:00'), as.POSIXct('2012-03-07 00:00')`. after convert as numeric form the output is like 2012030101,2012030102....2012030323,2012030100. But in my dataset the time is already numeric and there is  2012030124 instead of 2012030100. So, in 4th line when you wrote `time=as.vector(time[i])` then we will lost all value of 2012030124! is there any way to make 2012030124 by using `POSIXct`?

Answer (score 1):

```
library(ncdf)
nc<-open.ncdf("2012_03_05_PM10_surface.nc")
print(nc)

urban<-get.var.ncdf(nc,"urban")
time<-get.var.ncdf(nc,"TIME")
pm10<-get.var.ncdf(nc,"PM10")
tmsid<-get.var.ncdf(nc,"TMSID")

urban<-as.data.frame(t(urban))
colnames(urban)<- c("ID","LAT","LON")

dates<-seq(as.POSIXct("2012-03-01:01:00"),
           as.POSIXct("2012-03-08:00:00"), by="1 hour")
dates.numeric <-as.numeric(format(dates, "%Y%m%d%H"))

i<-tmsid %in% urban$ID & time %in% dates.numeric
urban1to7<-data.frame(ID=as.vector(tmsid[i]), 
              time= as.vector(time[i]),
              PM10=as.vector(pm10[i]))
urban1to7<-merge(urban1to7,urban,by="ID")
urban311<-subset(urban1to7, time=2012030101)

#urban sites,seoul area,7 days,every hour
seoul1to7<-subset(urban1to7,LAT>=36.8 & LAT<=38 & LON>=126.4 & LON<=127.3)

# make a list where there is (7*24) data frames
lapply(unique(seoul1to7$time), function(x) subset(seoul1to7, time==x))
```

In this way we can make a list by lapply which contains (7*24) data frames.